# How do we retrieve user ID and iam token with below curl request?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

As a federated user, it must use an API key or one-time passcode to authenticate. I have tried to execute that the below curl request:-

Example :-

Input :-

```
curl -s -u 'bx:bx' -k -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d "grant_type=password&response_type=cloud_iam,ims_portal&username=${1}&password=${2}&ims_account=${3}" https://iam.ng.bluemix.net/oidc/token
```

Output :-

```
"errorMessage":"You cannot authenticate with user name and password, as you are a federated user","errorDetails":"Your user id '<<><><>>' is federated and must use an API key or one-time passcode to authenticate"
```

But how we authenticate the user to generate the iam_token and iam_user_id?

Reference :-
https://softlayer.github.io/rest/IBMidtoSLKey/

Answer (score 1):

The code snippet you reference from the SoftLayer guide has the result of setting the SoftLayer Username and API key:

```
echo "SL_USERNAME: $SL_USERNAME"
echo "SL_API_KEY: $SL_API_KEY"
```

This is a roundabout way to find the same information that is listed as API Username and Authentication Key seen in your [User Profile](https://control.softlayer.com/account/user/profile). If you do not see an API username and Authentication Key, you can create one on the Actions menu next to your name in the [User List](https://control.softlayer.com/account/users).

You can then execute Infrastructure APIs, which I expect is the ultimate goal.

```
export IAAS_USERNAME=<API Username>
export IAAS_KEY=<Authentication Key>
curl -u $IAAS_USERNAME:$IAAS_KEY https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getAllBillingItems
```

It's unclear if the discussion around IAM tokens is necessary. Please provide more guidance on what you're trying to achieve if the above suggestion is insufficient.